# Going deeper into facebook's graph: collecting friends available data

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am building an PHP website using Facebook Graph API's and I can only read and collect very basic data.
    I managed to collect the one-line informations from my profile:

```
Ex:              
 $user_profile['hometown'];
 $user_profile['bio'];
 $user_profile['name'];
 $user_profile['id'];
```

printscreen 1: http://postimg.org/image/fsj6w4dtz/

First of all, I want to collect for the current user logged in, the education data for example: 
        *how should I collect this data, because $user_profile['education']; it is not working? What do I have to do if I want to collect informations about the users education (such as school, year, class-mates, type?)

printscreen 2:

> [image: collecting "multi-lines" data]

My main focus is finding a way to get for the current user loggedin, all of his friends data (such as name, events, bio, birthday, everything they let me to :d) 
       *I've googled and read part of the facebook API's docs but I dont really understand how to do this. I know this is possible, because I have tested with this tool: developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?

printscreen 3:

> [image: collecting friends data]

** *below is a image of trying to read the friends's infos, but for sure its wrong (anyway it doesnt work):* **postimg.org/image/4dg8khj77/**

Comment: Thanks to @Rahil Arora I succeded. Here is the solution: http://postimg.org/image/mfdivz1nn/ * Tho those are only my data, further I will try to fetch my friends data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are struggling while accessing the object that the API returns. [Facebook PHP API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) returns the decoded JSON object and therefore you must understand how to access data in a JSON decoded PHP object. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271063/php-accessing-decoded-json) to see how you can do that.

Therefore, in this case, you can simply access the deeper levels of a decoded JSON object by doing something as: `$user_profile->education->school->name`

Comment: As you said, this is working:   "$json = '{"hometown": {"id": "109823965708313", "name": "Straja, Neamt, Romania"},"id": "100001057214987"}';
 $obj = json_decode($json);
 echo $obj->hometown->name;"                                                       but I passed to $json a "manually" string. I cant manage to use the https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=hometown,bio&access_token='  because I dont understand from where do I get this acces token

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/

Comment: I already have a login + a seesion made. I read the doc from the link you provided but it did not help me at all

Comment: You'll have to obtain an Access Token by making an HTTP GET request to the following OAuth endpoint:

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
   client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
   &client_secret={app-secret}
   &code={code-parameter}`

And this will return an Access Token for you.

Comment: Do I have to use curl for this HTTP GET? how do I write this request into my php page? Thanks for your patience

Comment: Yes. You can use cURL. You just have to make an HTTP request using there parameters and in response, you'll receive an access token that you can use. You can find a lot of tutorials on its usage on the web and also on the Facebook developers website. 

Here is an example for this: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: I've downloaded the example and manged to generate the Acces Token. When I apply the json_decode to a string, it works, but when I apply it to what this link returns,  (graph.facebook.com/me?fields=hometown,bio&access_token=[AcessToken]'), it is not working. Please see this image for a detalied explanation: (things with red border are not working) http://postimg.org/image/e5vryppa5/

Comment: It should work fine. Try decoding is using `$obj = json_decode($ajson, true);` and then to retrieve the values, use `$obj['bio']`.

Comment: Try accessing the events in a similar way. Use `$user_profile['events']['data'][1]['timezone']`

Comment: I've tried to decode as you said, and also I`ve tried to acces the events in a similar way, but none worked. I checked the Acces Token, is still avalaible, it should work..

Comment: It worked at last. I did not fetch properly the data. Frist, I had to fetch the data     $ajson = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=events&access_token=<token>'); then to decode it:     $Vobj = json_decode($Vajson, true); and last thing, to acces what I wanted: $bio_dynamic = $obj['bio']; Thank you very much for the time.